# How to make a text field that can be entered when the user clicks it but otherwise is disabled?

Tags: android, android-studio

I think I'm missing something very obvious here.

All I want is a field where users can enter a parameter that affects the app, for example `-100`

I want the field to be visible on the screen, displaying the current value of the parameter, but not with a cursor in it or underlined in red or anything. Simply visible, but if the user wants to change the parameter, they can click in the box and change the value.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `.isDisabled` property of `TextInputLayout`. The moment user clicks back or save button or other view, you just set it to disabled. This way, it will be visible but not editable.

Comment: When you disable the `TextInputLayout` underline will remain there, which is not required as per question. Also `OnTouchListener` won't work once View is disabled.

Comment: @FahadNasrullah Underline's visibility can easily be toggled. And, a transparent view can be placed on top of it when it's disabled for listening touch events. But, I prefer a separate button like a save and edit button and that's how I use it.

Comment: Is there some other widget that does what I want, just not perhaps in exactly the way I described? It seems like quite a common use case I would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add both `TextView` and `EditText` in your layout, then show and hide based on your need.

Just show `EditText` by default and add `TextWatcher` on it, when enter is pressed or saved, then show your `TextView` with value from `EditText`. Then write `onClickListener` for `TextView` to show `EditText` again.

Hope that makes sense.